# MySQL Query to display records from table

Tags: mysql

I have a query.I have table with two columns country and state.I want to display columns in following format

```
Country       State            
----------- ---------
India        Delhi
             Bangalore   
             Kolkata
             Mumbai


USA          California
             Florida
             Las Vegas
             Virginia
```

It means "India" just appear one time in country column and and repeated values would come as blank value in country column when i select country and state from table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can format the data from front end just do a simple join with group by country

Comment: for java developer it would not create much problem but i am clueless about executing query for this requirement in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presentation is usually if not always better done outside of SQL so I'd recommend doing this in whatever your presentation layer runs, but if it's a requirement for the query, you *can* do it using session variables;

```
SELECT Country, State FROM (
  SELECT IF(Country=@country, '', Country) Country, State, @country := Country
  FROM (SELECT Country, State FROM Table1 ORDER BY Country, State) dummy1, 
       (SELECT @country:='') dummy2
) dummy3;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52012/8).

Just to show a (probably) better way, you can use this to get a list of states per country, and process it further in your presentation layer;

```
SELECT Country, GROUP_CONCAT(State) FROM Table1 GROUP BY Country;
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52012/9).

Comment: I know 2nd query but I want to do it MySql.Actually this question was asked in the interview.

Comment: Thanks Joachim Isaksson.Executing First query solves my problem.

Comment: SELECT Country, state FROM (
  SELECT IF(Country=@country, '', Country) Country, state, @country := Country from 
  (select country,state from table1 order by country,state) temp1) temp2;

This query also  output same result.

Answer (score -2):

use pl/sql.Moreover your table would be voilating 5th normal form.

Comment: What pl/sql?  The OP is using mysql, not oracle.